# hide and show a ui nav bar button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I am having a situation in which I have to hide the button on the right side of nav bar. Button name is btnRefresh, and I can hide it successfully by this way

```
self.nvbar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = nil
```

but when I use this for showing it again, it didn't get displayed again

```
self.nvbar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = btnRefresh
```

Any help???

Comment: Can you use the navigationItem rather than the topItem of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the tint color to clear and disable the button as the following :

```
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
barButtonItem.tintColor = .clear
barButtonItem.isEnabled = false
```

And to display it again change the color and enable it again :

```
barButtonItem.tintColor = .black 
barButtonItem.isEnabled = true
```